# How to link a file to in-app product in Google developers Console

Tags: android, in-app-billing

I am developing an android app with in-app billing. I want the user to be able to buy a .db file. I have created a in-app product in Developer Console with Id and description and it is active as well. The thing I don't understand is where to upload my .db file? How to link my in-app product to the file I want user to buy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have many choices, but none probably as simple as you were looking for as you will have to manually get hold of the file once the purchase is complete.
Some choices are :

- Either build the .db file into your APK and only allow access after
  purchase
- Make it part of a [APK expansion file](http://developer.android.com/google/play/expansion-files.html)
- Host the file on your own web-server, [EC2](http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/) or equivalent
- Use a BaaS provider such as [Parse](http://www.parse.com)

Any many,many more options besides